# Finding limits through rational/irrational paths

Tags: calculus, limits

Given

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x \,\,\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q} \\0\,\,\text{if } x \in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}.$$

I'm interested in showing

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0.$$

This is clear either straight from the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit or a simple application of squeeze theorem. I was thinking about an alternative way of showing...

Suppose we know $\lim_{x\to 0} x = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} 0 = 0$, can we claim $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = 0$ from $$\lim_{x\to 0\\x\in\mathbb{Q}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0\\x\in\mathbb{Q}} x = 0\,,$$ and
$$\lim_{x\to 0 \\ x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus{\mathbb{Q}}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0 \\ x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus{\mathbb{Q}}} 0 = 0?$$

I feel this is somewhat similar to how we show a limit by showing the left and right hand limit, since it covers all the real numbers? On the other hand, it feels like we are showing a limit existence by showing it's the same going through two different paths. Something feels fishy here. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Just check that $|f(x)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x| <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is fishy.

You have to show that limit along any path (i.e. sequence) is zero. 
What you are showing is that limit along either a completely rational or a completely irrational path leads to zero. 
There are paths to zero that consist of both rational and irrational numbers : for example, $a_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$, which need to be covered properly.

Comment: but if you show that any path must consist of any number in either sequence. that would be fine, isn't it? albeit it's a long winded way of showing it via definition.

Comment: @David Indeed, but it does use the alternate definition of limit of a function in terms of sequences (not the $\epsilon-\delta$), which is what you might have been looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#In_terms_of_sequences